# Flexbox layout issue in adobe xd plugins

Tags: css, flexbox, adobe-xd

In adobe xd when i use **flex-wrap** children element overlaps with each other

example 
[image: children element overlaps with each other]
code:

```
 <div
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          flexWrap: "wrap",
          height: 400,
          width: 600,
          border: "solid 1px #ddd",
          overflow: "scroll"
        }}
      >
        {this.state.images.map(({ png, description }, i) => (
          <img
            style={{
              border: "solid 1px #ddd",
              padding: 7,
              margin: 4,
              borderRadius: 4,
              display: "flex",
              flexDirection: "column"
            }}
            alt={description}
            src={png}
            key={i}
            height={64}
            width={64}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
```

But if i use smaller image size it does not overlaps

example
[image]
code

```
  <div
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          flexWrap: "wrap",
          height: 400,
          width: 600,
          border: "solid 1px #ddd",
          overflow: "scroll"
        }}
      >
        {this.state.images.map(({ png, description }, i) => (
          <img
            style={{
              border: "solid 1px #ddd",
              padding: 7,
              margin: 4,
              borderRadius: 4,
              display: "flex",
              flexDirection: "column"
            }}
            alt={description}
            src={png}
            key={i}
            height={34}
            width={34}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
```

I cant reproduce this error in browser looks like its only in adobe xd plugins

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug in the current version of XD. Thanks for reporting it. We have a fix coming your way in the future XD updates (possibly XD 20 or 21). Please stay tuned!

Comment: is the bug with flexbox? and any idea how to design the layout ?

Comment: This is a bug in how flexbox is implemented in XD. You are still free to use Flexbox if your use case don't run into above described issue. Also, regular CSS should always work.